# Как правильно конфигурировать разные реализации одного интерфейса?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть сервис по работе с изображениями.

У него есть интерфейс ImageServiceContract с 2 публичными методами:
getPath(),deleteImage() - этого достаточно другим сервисам. Более конкретную реализацию можно опустить.
Есть сервис статей которые работают с изображениями и сервис пользователей, который тоже работает с изображениями.

Я не хочу конфигурировать сервис изображений на уровне сервиса или контроллера, а забиваю настройки на уровне сервис провайдера, чтобы в теории я мог поменять место хранения изображения (бд или удаленный сервис) не затрагивая сервисы статей и пользователей.

Чтобы этот реализовать, я создаю еще 2 интерфейса ArticleImageServiceContract и UserImageServiceContract.

Собственно вопрос: нужно под них создавать пустые классы, которые наследуют ImageService. Или просто к ImageService прицепить еще 2 интерфейса (что выглядит немного странно, но меньше кода)?

Вариант 1:

```
interface ImageServiceContract{
  public function getPath();
  public function deleteImage();
}
interface ArticleImageServiceContract extends ImageServiceContract;
interface UserImageServiceContract extends ImageServiceContract;

class ImageService implements ImageServiceContract, ArticleImageServiceContract, UserImageServiceContract{

    private $dir;
    private $width;
    private $height;

    public function __construct(string $dir, int $width, $height)
    {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    public function getPath();
    public function deleteImage();
}




class ImageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind(ArticleImageServiceContract::class, function () {
            return new ImageService(
                'images/articles',
                '512',
                '512'
            );
        });

       $this->app->bind(UserImageServiceContract::class, function () {
            return new ImageService(
                'images/users',
                '100',
                '100'
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
interface ImageServiceContract{
  public function getPath();
  public function deleteImage();
}

interface ArticleImageServiceContract extends ImageServiceContract;
interface UserImageServiceContract extends ImageServiceContract;

class ImageService implements ImageServiceContract{

    private $dir;
    private $width;
    private $height;

    public function __construct(string $dir, int $width, $height)
    {
        $this->dir = $dir;
        $this->width = $width;
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    public function getPath();
    public function deleteImage();
}

class ArticleImageService extends ImageService implements ArticleImageServiceContract{

}
class UserImageService extends ImageService implements UserImageServiceContract{

}

class ImageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app->bind(ArticleImageServiceContract::class, function () {
            return new ArticleImageService(
                'images/articles',
                '512',
                '512'
            );
        });

       $this->app->bind(UserImageServiceContract::class, function () {
            return new UserImageService(
                'images/users',
                '100',
                '100'
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы на Вашем месте вообще отказался бы от этих костылей.

Смотрите, есть решение получше для этого случая, из [коробки](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/container#binding-basics) (Binding Primitives раздел)

```
$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\UserController')
          ->needs('$imageService')
          ->give(new ImageService(
              'images/users',
              '100',
              '100'
          ));

$this->app->when('App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController')
          ->needs('$imageService')
          ->give(new ImageService(
              'images/articles',
              '512',
              '512'
          ));
```

Или [Contextual Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/container#contextual-binding)

```
$this->app->when(UserController::class)
          ->needs(ImageService::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new ImageService(
                  'images/users',
                  '100',
                  '100'
              );
          });

$this->app->when(ArticleController::class)
          ->needs(ImageService::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new ImageService(
                  'images/articles',
                  '512',
                  '512'
              );
          });
```

Comment: Спасибо что напомнили об этом функционале, а если например это было бы Симфони или другой фрейм? Не везде же есть такая гибкая настройка контейнера.

Comment: @Pavel симфоневский container на самом деле из коробке более гибкий чем ларовский (как по мне) - в симфони Вы можете в `services.yaml`, например указать контроллеру какой сервис с какими параметрами нужно создать.

Comment: А если взять ситуацию, что в одном контроллере 1 сервис с разными конфигами 2 раза вызывается? Тогда уже 2 интерфейса?

Comment: @Pavel мне почему-то кажется, что можно написать примерно как в роуте `App\Http\Controllers\UserController@action`, но лично не пробовал